# replace all "\" with "\\" python

Tags: python, regex

Does anyone know how replace all `\` with `\\` in python?
Ive tried:

```
re.sub('\','\\',string)
```

But it screws it up because of the escape sequence.
does anyone know the awnser to my question?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: @gnibbler `r'\'` is not valid.

Comment: @JBernardo, heh, I just realised an deleted that comment, still why not just use the str method instead of regex? ie. `string.replace('\\',r'\\')`

Comment: @gnibbler As @Ignacio wrote, probably it isn't OP's real question... Maybe he's having trouble with windows paths or CRLF

Comment: @JBernardo, ah in that case, telling the OP that '/' works fine (instead of '\') in windows paths may or may not help :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just need to escape the backslashes in your strings: *(also there's no need for regex stuff)*

```
>>> s = "cats \\ dogs"
>>> print s
cats \ dogs
>>> print s.replace("\\", "\\\\")
cats \\ dogs
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You either need re.sub("\\\\","\\\\\\\\",string) or re.sub(r'\\', r'\\\\', string) because you need to escape each slash twice ... once for the string and once for the regex.

Answer (score 7):

you should do:

```
re.sub(r'\\', r'\\\\', string)
```

As `r'\'` is not a valid string

BTW, you should always use raw (`r''`) strings with regex as many things are done with backslashes.

Comment: This doesn't work. You either need re.sub("\\\\","\\\\\\\\",string) or re.sub(r'\\', r'\\\\', string) because you need to escape each slash twice ... once for the string and once for the regex.

Comment: Still doesn't work. You are trying to replace a literal \ with the first part of a regex escape for special character, so it complains: "error: unexpected end of regular expression"

Comment: @ecounysis You're totally right. I hadn't tried in the interpreter... :(

Answer (score 3):

You either need `re.sub("\\\\","\\\\\\\\",string)` or `re.sub(r'\\', r'\\\\', string)` because you need to escape each slash twice ... once for the string and once for the regex.

```
>>> whatever = r'z\w\r'
>>> print whatever
z\w\r
>>> print re.sub(r"\\",r"\\\\", whatever)
z\\w\\r
>> print re.sub("\\\\","\\\\\\\\",whatever)
z\\w\\r
```

Answer (score 3):

You should escape backslashes, and also you don't need regex for this simple operation:

```
>>> my_string = r"asd\asd\asd\\"
>>> print(my_string)
asd\asd\asd\\
>>> replaced = my_string.replace("\\", "\\\\")
>>> print(replaced)
asd\\asd\\asd\\\\
```

Comment: This does work in the interpreter, but fails when I run in the program. Weird. May be I'm doing something stupid.